# How to Crop the GoogleAPI QR code image in Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

As we all know google provide as Free API named:[developer.google.com](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes)

but this api has some limitation that we cannot customize according to us. but its simple and effective for small needs. 
So, what I trying to do is crop the QR code so that its looks fit.

**An example is below:**

[image: qr]

**URL:**

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8" title="Link to Google.com" />
```

As in above example you see it contain the the padding(spaces) is quite large from the edges of the QR-image. What I want is to remove(cropout) these space from the edges of the image so that it look like an **example below**:

[image: qr new]

**bootstrap:**

```
   <tr>
         <th>QR Code</th>
          <td  class ="text-left">
          <img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8" title="Link to Google.com" />

            </td>

   </tr>
```

**output:**

[image: here]

**Goal:**

[image: here]

Yes I know QR-generator Libraries would be the better option here but my main focus is on charts.googleapis if anyone give a direction or suggestion that would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit what you need play with the value of `background-size` and `background-position` to adjust it :

```
.img-thumbnail{
  background: url('https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8');
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-size: 135% 140%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Try this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hr8ak91o/

Comment: thank you so much amine for your efforts. but  its not works for shot urls. if you use any other url the qr code structure is imbalanced. hence unable to read by QR CODE SCANNER

Comment: You are welcome, can you give me the url that you've tried?

Comment: you can try any long or shot url yourself. just google any find any of those.

Comment: Yeah i tried short url and it works, check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gmtr7ksn/

Answer (score 6):

Navjot. I hope it's still in time for an answer to your question, and certainly it is for many people who'll read it in search for a solution for their own problem.

If you've read the API's docs, as I presume you have, you surely haven't found clear explanation on how to control this specific aspect of the QR code chart.

Here is the answer: you'll have to set the `chld` parameter, which is a double parameter, for it controls the error correction level **and** the margin as well. These two subparameters have to appear separated by an "|". According to the API docs, the error correction level parameter can take the values below:

- L - [Default] Allows recovery of up to 7% data loss;
- M - Allows recovery of up to 15% data loss;
- Q - Allows recovery of up to 25% data loss;
- H - Allows recovery of up to 30% data loss;

Data loss recovery capability takes a toll on data carrying capacity. The more data loss recovery capability the less useful data can be carried by the resulting QR code image.

In turn, the margin parameter is "the width of the white border around the data portion of the code. This is in rows, not in pixels. ... The default value is 4." A row corresponds to the width of one of the squares that compose the QR code.
The code:

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8&chld=M|0" title="Link to Google.com" />
```

renders an image with 0 margin and medium-low error recovery capability:
[QR code with 0 margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtKdo.png)

Thanks to [Mathew Sachin](https://mathewsachin.in/blog/2017/01/03/make-qr-code.html), who shows the use of this parameter in his blog.